# JavaScript: store function method to variable

Tags: javascript, methods, assign

I have a variable `a` that can be either an object or an array of objects. I have an array `array`.

I want to append `a` to `array`, so I thought of using either `Array.prototype.push.call` or `Array.prototype.push.apply` with a ternary operator as follows:

```
var a = "hello"; // or var a = ["hello", "world"];
var array = [];
var append = ($.isArray(a)) ? Array.prototype.push.apply : Array.prototype.push.call;
append(array, a); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

(`$` being jQuery)

I'm new to JavaScript and I guess there is a good reason why this doesn't work but I couldn't find it. Can't `apply` or `call` be assigned to a variable? (They are not real functions?) Or is something missing on the call to `append()`?

Note: I know I could do this with `if/else` but I'd rather like to understand why I can't assign these methods to a variable and call it.

---

**Minor additional question**: I want to do this because I get `a` from a JSON API and if I understand correctly, JSON can't contain arrays of one single object. Although I feel that what I'm trying to do must be very common, I also couldn't find how other developers deal with this. Is there a better way than testing whether `a` is an array or not and use `apply()` or not accordingly?

Comment: `array = array.concat(a);` And it would be easier if `a` is always an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `call` and `apply` are instance methods. They are critical to the context object `this`.

Eventually you should execute `append.call(Array.prototype.push, array, a)` because `call` or `apply` need function `push` to be passed as `this`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any if, just use `concat`

```
var array = [];
var a = "hello"; // or var a = ["hello", "world"]
array = array.concat(a);
```

Comment: True, but this doesn't really answer the question.